# How to Create a Friendly URL in a CS File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know how to create a url by using html.actionlink in the aspx file. But if I want to create the same url in a code behind file how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code behind idea for views in MVC was removed coz it didn't really seem to fit the MVC paradigm. Maybe you should consider [creating your own Html Helpers](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-preview-using-the-mvc-ui-helpers/) instead. Doing this, extending existing actions like `Html.ActionLink()` is easy (and heaps of fun).

This example shows how i created a helper to tweak my login/logout links. Some ppl might argue whether this is a good use for a helper but it works for me:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// For the global MasterPage's footer
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string FooterEditLink(this HtmlHelper helper,
        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity user, string loginText, string logoutText)
    {
        if (user.IsAuthenticated)
            return System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(helper, logoutText, "Logout", "Account",
                new { returnurl = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath }, null);
        else
            return System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(helper, loginText, "Login", "Account",
                new { returnurl = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath }, null);
    }
```

..and this is how i use it in the view (partial view to be exact):

```
<% =Html.FooterEditLink(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, "Edit", "Logout (" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + ")")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post by Scott Mitchell

http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/posts/14011.aspx

(Since you say 'html.actionlink' which is an instance of the UrlHelper class I am assuming you are in a context where you don't have access to an instance of the UrlHelper class)